# Linux Containers lxc-create

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lxc, linux-containers

I've been trying to work on Linux Containers (lxc). Post installation, I tried to create a container. I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04, with lxc-1.1.1. I'm prompted with this error when i try to create a new container :

lxc-create: error while loading shared libraries: liblxc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory. 
Any help in overcoming this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Check you LD_LIBRARY_PATH , say '/usr/local/lib' and see if  liblxc shared libs are available there , if not search those under  /usr/ and copy them to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install liblxc1` first, userspace tools come from a different package than libraries

Answer (score 1):

You need to add /usr/local/lib to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

Try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` and then try `lxc-create` again.